# Stripe migrating from token based to payment intent based charges

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

Previously I was using stripe with another third party service called Zuora. I was generating a token like so on the front end

```
const tokenOptions = {
  name: form.fullName,
  address_country: form.country,
  address_zip: form.zip
};

const cardElement = stripeElements.getElement(CardElement);

const { error, token } = await stripe.createToken(
  cardElement,
  tokenOptions
);

// use `token.id` on the BE to make the charge
```

And then passing `token.id` to the back end which hit Zuora's endpoint that actually made the charge using this token id.

But apparently the token approach doesn't support 3D Secure which we want to implement. The other approach of using Payment Intents does support SD secure however. So I replaced the above code with:

```
const getClientSecret = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/create-payment-intent', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});

const { client_secret } = await getClientSecret.json();

const paymentIntent = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
      name: 'Foo bar',
      email: 'foo@bar.com'
    }
  }
});
```

My `create-payment-intent` endpoint on the backend looks like this:

```
router.post("/api/create-payment-intent", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
      amount: 100,
      currency: "usd",
      capture_method: "manual",
    });
    res.status(200).json({
      client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
    });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
  }
});
```

Now this call:

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(client_secret, {
  payment_method: {
    card: cardElement,
    billing_details: {
      name: 'Foo bar',
      email: 'foo@bar.com'
    }
  }
});
```

returns an object like this:

```
paymentIntent: {
  amount: 100,
  canceled_at: null,
  cancellation_reason: null,
  capture_method: "manual",
  client_secret: "some-secret-id-here",
  confirmation_method: "automatic",
  created: 1626287910,
  currency: "usd",
  description: null,
  id: "pi_1JDCyYCmZFHcp9eoF2MoVeyg",
  last_payment_error: null,
  livemode: false,
  next_action: null,
  object: "payment_intent",
  payment_method: "pm_1JDCyYCmZFHcp9eoZHAfkoCX",
  payment_method_types: ["card"],
  receipt_email: null,
  setup_future_usage: null,
  shipping: null,
  source: null,
  status: "requires_capture"
}
```

My question is can I use one of the values inside the return object in place of the token id that I was using before to make the charge at a later time from Zuora?

Can I use `paymentIntent.id` for this?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, your code *is* currently creating a payment. When you call `confirmCardPayment()`, your code is creating a Charge under the hood.

Specifically, it has "authorized" a charge but not yet captured it, as can be seen by the `status: "requires_capture"` status of the PaymentIntent in your response.

If you're looking to send something to Zoura for a later charge, what you're looking for is the modern equivalent to a Token i.e. a PaymentMethod object.

In your response, the PaymentMethod in question is the   `payment_method: "pm_1JDCyYCmZFHcp9eoZHAfkoCX",` field from the response in `confirmCardPayment`.

That PaymentMethod represents a card (similar to what the legacy Token did) and that is what you'd need to create a charge later.

Comment: hey thanks a lot for the reply! So you're saying I should use the `payment_method` value in the response of `confirmCardPayment()` to send to Zoura  to make the charge. But you also say that function already creates a charge. How can I get the `payment_method` value without creating a charge?

Comment: you call `createPaymentMethod()` from Stripe.js: https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods/create_payment_method

Comment: unfortunately `createPaymentMethod()` doesn't trigger the 3d secure check only `confirmCardPayment` does that for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/60660952/16426252

Comment: oh you want to set it up for 3DS first ... you need to create a SetupIntent server-side, then call `confirmCardSetup()` on your webpage

Comment: thanks again for answering my annoying questions!  I did as you said and created a setup intent on the server side which gave me a `client_secret` that I then used to call `confirmCardSetup()` on the front end. This did invoke the 3D secure check! And it also didn't create a charge (confirmed by checking my dashboard).

Now the last question is, what can I use from the return object of this `confirmCardSetup()` call to make the charge later (via Zoura)? Is it the `setupIntent.id`, `setupIntent.payment_method`, something else? Or do I need to  make more calls after this to get what I need?

Comment: The last comment is old but in case anyone else looks for a similar answer, you can charge later by creating a new paymentintent with the customer id and payment method id you would have gathered when creating the original setupintent.